# Best way to get needed info from the logfile

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have following lines in my logfiles

```
14:40:21.581 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:24.144 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:25.175 MC: <DataContainer>
<EquipmentHeartbeat dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:21.00+01:00" interval="300" recipeId="ES-AD0109071F-3C-PS.ASP"/>
</DataContainer>
14:40:26.675 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:29.206 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:29.675 INFO MobileConnection: Creating new GlobalLLWData completed, Milliseconds used: 0
14:40:30.769 SMDMachine.keepAlive() frequency:18 pr second.
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.2.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.5.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.11.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.13.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.14.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.15.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.17.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.612 INFO McDevicePosition.ReelMethods.GetSplicingChainInformation(): LazyFetch on position 2.18.1 (current ReelID=??)
14:40:31.737 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:34.269 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:36.800 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:39.326 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:42.029 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:44.545 In stopmachine. rtfBoxStop=false,secsGemStop=false,ht=false,error=1007, multiBoxStop=false stoptext=null
14:40:45.764 MC: <DataContainer>
<EquipmentInformation dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.31+01:00" laneList="1" zoneList="1-3" informationId="ReportPPM"><Extensions><ReportPPM dateTimeStart="2011-04-06T14:43:05.31+01:00" dateTimeEnd="2011-04-06T14:43:42.31+01:00" PcbID="1302014560"><Nozzle headId="1-0-PHHA1" numberOfPickAttempts="8" numberOfPlacements="8"/><Nozzle headId="2-0-PHHA1" numberOfPickAttempts="16" numberOfPlacements="16"/></ReportPPM></Extensions></EquipmentInformation>
<EquipmentInformation dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" laneList="1" zoneList="1-3" informationId="ReportPPM"><Extensions><ReportPPM dateTimeStart="2011-04-06T14:43:05.37+01:00" dateTimeEnd="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" PcbID="1302014560"><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="06" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0206.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.6.1" feederType="ITF2_24" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="09" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0209.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.9.1" feederType="ITF2_16" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="11" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0211.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.11.1" feederType="ITF2_12" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="13" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0213.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.13.1" feederType="ITF2_12" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="14" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0214.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.14.1" feederType="ITF2_12" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><MaterialHandler materialSupplyArea="02" trackId="16" feederDivision="001" materialHandlerId="0216.001" materialHandlerIdAlt="2.16.1" feederType="ITF2_16" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/></ReportPPM></Extensions></EquipmentInformation>
<EquipmentInformation dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" laneList="1" zoneList="1-3" informationId="ReportPPM"><Extensions><ReportPPM dateTimeStart="2011-04-06T14:43:05.37+01:00" dateTimeEnd="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" PcbID="1302014560"><Component componentId="IC0102667" partId="IC0102667F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><Component componentId="IC0102669" partId="IC0102669F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><Component componentId="IC0102665" partId="IC0102665F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><Component componentId="IC0102958" partId="IC0102958F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><Component componentId="IC0102671" partId="IC0102671F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/><Component componentId="XT0100253" partId="XT0100253F" lotId="" numberOfPickAttempts="4" numberOfPlacements="4"/></ReportPPM></Extensions></EquipmentInformation>
<EquipmentBlocked dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" previousState="READY-PROCESSING-EXECUTING" eventId="EquipmentBlocked"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked" previousSEMI-State="PRD/Regular production/Process product"/></EquipmentChangeState>
<EquipmentErrorsCleared dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" previousState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" eventId="EquipmentErrorsCleared"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked" previousSEMI-State="PRD/Regular production/Process product"/></EquipmentChangeState>
<EquipmentAlarmsCleared dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.37+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" previousState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" eventId="EquipmentAlarmsCleared"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked" previousSEMI-State="PRD/Regular production/Process product"/></EquipmentChangeState>
<ItemTransferIn dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:05.91+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" laneId="1"/>
<ItemTransferZone dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:05.91+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" fromZoneId="1" toZoneId="2" laneId="1"/>
<ItemWorkStart dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:05.91+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" laneId="1" zoneId="1-3" recipeId="ES-AD0109071F-3C-PS.ASP" orderId="asad"/>
<ItemWorkAbort dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.77+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" laneId="1" zoneId="2" abortId="Incomplete" cycleTime="35922" recipeId="ES-AD0109071F-3C-PS.ASP" orderId="asad"/>
<ItemTransferZone dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.77+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" fromZoneId="2" toZoneId="3" laneId="1"/>
<ItemTransferOut dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.77+01:00" itemInstanceId="1302014560" laneId="1"><Extensions><itemInfo itemTransferInTime="2011-04-06T14:43:05.91+01:00" itemTransferOutTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.77+01:00" cycleTime="35922" recipeId="ES-AD0109071F-3C-PS.ASP" orderId="asad" itemInstanceId="1302014560" statusId="Incomplete"/></Extensions><Extensions><machineConfig flowlineName="AX-1" machineName="1-1-AX-1_AX201" machineManufacturer="Assembleon" machineModel="AX-201" machineSerial="DC606" machineVersion="n.a." machineSoftwareVersion="3.10_930_26"/></Extensions><Extensions><PlacementSummary totalPlaced="" totalAttempts=""/></Extensions></ItemTransferOut>
<EquipmentStarved dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-STARVED" previousState="READY-IDLE-BLOCKED" eventId="EquipmentStarved"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Starved" previousSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked"/></EquipmentChangeState>
<EquipmentErrorsCleared dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-STARVED" previousState="READY-IDLE-STARVED" eventId="EquipmentErrorsCleared"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Starved" previousSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked"/></EquipmentChangeState>
<EquipmentAlarmsCleared dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00"/>
<EquipmentChangeState dateTime="2011-04-06T14:43:42.84+01:00" currentState="READY-IDLE-STARVED" previousState="READY-IDLE-STARVED" eventId="EquipmentAlarmsCleared"><Extensions currentSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Starved" previousSEMI-State="SBY/No product/Blocked"/></EquipmentChangeState>
</DataContainer>
14:40:45.764 Curr State=READY-IDLE-STARVED; Curr SemiState=SBY/No product/Starved; Curr Event Id=EquipmentAlarmsCleared
14:40:45.764 INFO Changing status to WaitBoard
```

What will be the best way here to get all the instances of the time with the information stored between  and  data from the log file as some tupple ? I have a lot returns of it in the log and i need to catch all of them.

I thought to do it with indexof string function but it is comes to be too complex.
Maybe it's a good idea to use regex here ? (the problem i have no clue regarding regexes)

Comment: From this log, you want only the two entries with `<DataContainer>`? Can we assume that the opening tag is on the same line as the time and that the closing tag is on its own line?

Comment: @svick: I want to all entries as some tuple list <the time , what was between the datacontainer> , and your two assumptions are ok .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
static readonly Regex DataContainerRegex =
    new Regex(@"^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\d) MC: (<DataContainer>.*?</DataContainer>)",
              RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);

static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, XDocument>> Parse(string data)
{
    var matches = DataContainerRegex.Matches(data);

    return from Match match in matches
           let date = DateTime.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value,
                                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           let doc = XDocument.Parse(match.Groups[2].Value)
           select Tuple.Create(date, doc);
}
```

If you really wanted the text between `<DataContainer>` instead of a `XDocument`, just place the parentheses around `.*?` directly and parse the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt at parsing the sample logfile:

```
static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, string>> GetLogEntries(string path)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"^(\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\.\d{3}\s)(.*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    var logLineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    Match currentMatch = null;

    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        var match = regex.Match(line);

        if (match.Success && logLineBuilder.Length != 0)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(DateTime.Parse(currentMatch.Groups[1].Value), logLineBuilder.ToString());
            logLineBuilder.Clear();
        }

        if (match.Success)
            currentMatch = match;

        logLineBuilder.AppendLine(match.Success ? match.Groups[2].Value : line);
    }

    yield return Tuple.Create(DateTime.Parse(currentMatch.Groups[1].Value), logLineBuilder.ToString());
}
```

I thought the log file might be big so I've used [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) which will read the log file one line at a time. This should keep the memory footprint down because it doesn't have to read the whole file into memory. This can be an issue with particularly large log files. You should then be able to filter any additional criteria using a LINQ expression e.g.:

```
var entries = GetLogEntries("logfile.txt");

var dataContainers = from e in entries
                     where e.Item2.IndexOf("MC: <DataContainer>") != -1
                     select XDocument.Parse(e.Item2.Substring(3));

Console.WriteLine(dataContainers.Count()); //prints "2"
```